# How run XeLaTeX with the latexmake python library?

Tags: xetex, latexmk

I am automating the creation of documents with python and I ran into the latexmake library.
However, I have not found any way to make it run with XeLaTeX which I need.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but you don't necessarily need xelatex for fontawesome5.

Comment: yes sorry samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz but I have some packages that are not compatible with pdfLateX and require XeLaTex

Comment: Are these packages compatible with lualatex? If yes, I would recommend this instead of xelatex.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz what would be the advantages ?

Comment: I would usually recommend lualatex instead of xelatex because the font lookup is more reliable. Also xelatex has problems with non-text links, shadings and some font colours.