# How to configure the Python library latexmake to run with luaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, latexmk, python

I am working on automated templates, and I want to use latexmake with luaLaTeX, as suggested in a comment on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691289/how-run-xelatex-with-the-latexmake-python-library), where I attempted a similar setup with XeLaTeX. However, I am facing challenges with the configuration. My goal is to automate the process of typesetting my documents with luaLaTeX using latexmake, and I believe this will save me a significant amount of time.

I have tried variations of `latexmake main.tex -lualatex -outdir=output -auxdir=auxil` in the terminal but it tells me that lualatex is not recognized as an argument

For the code examples, I have a template that works and needs lualatex but needs several compilations. Hence the need for a latex maker.

I also have  tried to read the documentation for latexmake but I didn't find any solution and there isn't much content about this library online.

If someone could provide guidance on how to configure latexmake to work with luaLaTeX, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what exactly is not working? Please show some code and give more details.

Comment: according to google latexmake (which is not the same as latexmk in your tags) has been written in 2013, it is beta and the repo is dead. Why on earth are you trying to use it instead of a maintained tool like arara or latexmk?

Comment: I am using this because I am working in a python project and I don't know better ways to do it. latexmk uses Perl and arara needs a java virtual machine which are options that I would like to avoid. However if you would like to share other python latex-makers that work with luatex or xelatex, you are more thant welcome.

Comment: Everything Ulrike already said times 10. But, if you insist, to. use that thing, glancing a the [code](https://github.com/JanKanis/latexmk.py/blob/master/latexmake.py#L800) revealed an option `-t` which looks like it wants to take `lualatex` as a value

Answer (score 4):

An actively developed alternative to `latexmake.py` with almost no dependencies is `llmk`:

https://github.com/wtsnjp/llmk

[image]

It is already bundled with TeXLive and MiKTeX